# Unable to receive mails from same server

Tags: g-suite

We have created G Suite account(sup...@domain.com) with the domain inkwiry.com. Here we are receiving emails from any servers except domain hosted server. Means i have placed this email in the contact form, but emails are not receiving here because we are sending mails from same server.

I believe no issue in the code as we are able to send same mails to another email except sup...@domain.com. Can some one help me what are the settings I needs to include here.

Thanks in advance,
Sateesh

Answer (score 0):

The exact problem depends very much on *how* your form sends mail, so check your form and then, if you're using (the equivalent) of the local sendmail libs, check the mail log on your server for errors.

But as an educated guess: such a  problem is typically the result of using your domain name as the hostname for your server. Rather than routing email for your domain to the correct mailservers (i.e. those in the MX record for your domain) your server will try to deliver mail locally (and fail).

Changing the hostname of your server from your domain name `inkwiry.com` to for instance something more specific like `www.inkwiry.com` is then a quick resolution.